# SQL Server : how to get max of columns

Tags: sql-server, max

In SQL Server, please tell me how to get max of columns.

Data:

```
 QRY_ID  |  SUBJECT1  |  SUBJECT2 | ..........................  SUBJECT20
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   A     |    100     |    15     | ..........................     120   
   B     |    200     |    32     | ..........................     140  
   C     |    32      |    29     | ..........................     230  
   D     |    78      |    61     | ..........................     420  
   E     |    99      |    30     | ..........................     20
```

Desired result:

```
 QRY_ID  |  MAX(SUBJECT) | 
--------------------------
   A     |    120    |  
   B     |    200    |  
   C     |    230    |     
   D     |    420    |      
   E     |    99     |
```

Thanks ~!

Comment: Your question is fairly vague. Do you want the total of all the columns, the highest value of all columns for each row, or just the value of the final column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a version of SQL Server which support UNPIVOT, you can try:

```
SELECT      QRY_ID, MAX([VALUE]) AS [MAX(SUBJECT)]
FROM        MyTable
UNPIVOT
(
    [VALUE]
    FOR SUBJECT IN (SUBJECT1, SUBJECT2,...SUBJECTX)
) up
GROUP BY    QRY_ID;
```

Otherwise:

```
SELECT      QRY_ID, MAX(SUBJECT) AS [MAX(SUBJECT)]
FROM
(
    SELECT QRY_ID, SUBJECT1 AS SUBJECT FROM MyTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT QRY_ID, SUBJECT2 AS SUBJECT FROM MyTable
    UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT QRY_ID, SUBJECTX AS SUBJECT FROM MyTable
) t
GROUP BY    QRY_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT qry_id,MAX(subject1) FROM t GROUP BY qry_id
```

SqlFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69643/2) schema and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t 
    (
     qry_id varchar(1), 
     subject1 int
    );

INSERT INTO t
(qry_id, subject1)
VALUES
('A', 99),
('A', 100),
('E', 200),
('E', 40),
('D', 23),
('X', 60),
('B', 10);
```

Results:

```
QRY_ID  MAX_SUBJECT1
A       100
B       10
D       23
E       200
X       60
```